# How can I put Variables in URL's using django-qr-code

Tags: python, html, django, url, qr-code

I've been trying to generate URL's on a detailpage for my app. I want the url of the QR-Code to be a link to the detail page of the item. What i have right now is this:

`<img src="{% qr_url_from_text "localhost:8000/items/{{item.id}}" %}" alt="QR-Code for the item">`

the Problem with this is, that i want to give `item.id` as part of the url. But it's not seen as variable, so when i scan the qr-code, it opens the page `http://localhost:8000/items/{{item.id}}`, but i want it to have the actual id (e.g. 4) in the url, not {{item.id}} as string.

Is there any way to put variables in those URL names?

Thank you already

Answer (score 2):

Do not make url using variable in template.

Do it in view, as context variable, and than use that variable in place of "localhost:8000/items/{{item.id}}" in template .

So, in your view, you will have something like:

```
def yourview(request, pk):
    qrcode_url = "localhost:8000/items/" + str(pk)
    context = {
         qrcode_url: 'qrcode_url',
     }
     return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', context)
```

and than in template:

```
<img src='{% qr_url_from_text qrcode_url size="t" version=10 image_format="png" error_correction="L" %}' alt="QR code">
```